# Google Static Map API and 45 degree (oblique) imagery

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Is there anyway to get 45 degree imagery from the google static maps api?

I'm able to do it from the javascript api, but don't see similar access in the docs for the static maps api.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option currently to retrive 45 degree imagery.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: Do you know of anyway to capture a static image of the 45 degree imagery using the javascript api?

Comment: As one possible use API, you can generate a capture image of a browser using chrome extension. But it only works on chrome extension.